# SQL Inner Join w/ Unique Vals

Tags: sql

Questions similar to this one about using `DISTINCT` values in an `INNER JOIN` have been asked a few times, but I don't see my (simple) use case.

**Problem Description:**

I have two tables `Table A` and `Table B`.  They can be joined via a variable `ID`.  Each `ID` may appear on multiple rows in both `Table A` and `Table B`.

I would like to `INNER JOIN` `Table A` and `Table B` on the distinct values of `ID` which appear in `Table B` and select all rows of `Table A` with a `Table A.ID` which appears matching some condition in `Table B`.

**What I want:**

I want to make sure I get only one copy of each row of `Table A` with a `Table A.ID` matching a `Table B.ID` which satisfies `[some condition]`.

**What I would like to do:**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE B WHERE [some condition]
) ON TABLE A.ID=TABLE B.ID
```

**Additionally:**

As a further (really dumb) constraint, I can't say anything about the SQL standard in use, since I'm executing the SQL query through Stata's `odbc load` command on a database I have no information about beyond the variable names and the fact that "it does accept SQL queries," ( <- this is the extent of the information I have).

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows in `a` that match an id in `b`, then use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id);
```

Trying to use `join` just complicates matters, because it both filters and generates duplicates.

Comment: Thanks!  Does this also accept a condition on the rows in B?  So:
```Select A.*
from A
where exists (select 1 from B where B.ID = A.ID AND B.other_column == 42) ``` ?

Comment: @AsBrB . . . Yes, if you include the condition in the subquery.